# ANTD editable header row

Tags: javascript, typescript, header, antd

I need to make an editable header row in a table. I've tried manipulating the first row as a header row, while the real header is hidden. It works well, but I got a problem when turning it into a new page because the first row won't show up on the second page. Is there a possibility that I can customize and edit the table header row?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Table, Typography } from "antd";
import { data } from './data'


export const App = () => {
  const [editableStr, setEditableStr] = useState(
    "This is an editable text."
  );

  const columns = [
    {
      title: (
        <Typography.Text editable={{ onChange: setEditableStr }}>
          {editableStr}
        </Typography.Text>
      ),
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
    },
  ];

  return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
};
```

Comment: just tried with some adjustments, and it works very well. thank you!!